println is not printing in a java gradle application
Create a new java application in Intellij using Gradle


Click on the run icon at line 4 and select Run 'Main.main()'. Why "Hello World" is not printing?


I'm using latest version of Intellij.

It printed once yesterday when I deleted .idea folder and restarted intellij. Retried it many times but "Hello World" is not printing. How to get println to print messages?
Main.java
package org.example;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.10.0')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


What directory exactly did you delete and why?

Post of copy of that code as text, in addition to the image.

Try this solution

I cannot reproduce your issue. I have the same version of IntelliJ: IntelliJ IDEA 2024.3.1.1 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-243.22562.218, built on December 18, 2024.  I used your same settings in the New Project dialog, including "untitled" and Auto-select. My only difference is running on Java 23.0.1. And I am running on macOS Sonoma 14.7.2. My output is: 21:27:42: Executing ':org.example.Main.main()'…

Task :compileJava
Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
Task :classes


Task :org.example.Main.main()
Hello, World!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
…

You need to switch to the console tab to see the program output.

@aled somewhere I read deleting .iead folder and restarting intellij will fix the issue. It worked once but not after that.

@BasilBourque added Main.java and build.gradle to the question. I'm getting everything else except the message in println.

@SimonJacobs I'm not sure. what exactly I need to do?

@Robert I don't see any console tab. I see  only Run tab and Debug tab.

Something was wrong with intellij.
File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Restore Default Settings (You can also do it using Ctrl + Shift + A)
When IntelliJ restarts select "Skip Import". If you import old IDE settings you will face the same issue again.
Thank you everyone for the support.
